# What is size of FB cover image without cut sides in phone and tablet?

Tags: facebook, pixel, photoshop, designer

I want to make cover image for facebook. I am facing problem that cover image in mobile or mobile-app and in tablet is cut by both left and right side. How can i make it perfect. How much pixels do i need to space from sides so images will not be cut

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Standard full cover photo size for Facebook is **851 pixels wide** and **315 pixels tall**.

[Here are the dimensions for a Facebook timeline:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wNxH.png)

Comment: Yes i read it. below is my image that i need to set as cover
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BycOLWr5R3b1WjhQc19fY210TXc
But problem is that in mobile its cut of phone image by right hand side
If i move more from right to left side , Its look good in mobile but not in desktop/normal mode
How can i resolved this problem?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the output in mobile and web?

Comment: I want to post 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BycOLWr5R3b1WjhQc19fY210TXc/view
This image as fb cover. with good look in mobile as well in web. Currently Facbook cut image from left and right side when open in mobile.

Comment: Ahh I see. Well, that's because Facebook maintains the photo's quality by cropping it to fit in the smartphone's screen. It does not squeeze nor stretch the image to have it fit. This is a standard for Facebook and you won't be able to change it :)

You could reposition the image so as to have it focus on the area you wish the viewers to see (important section of the image).

Comment: thanks 
i think i have to change position. But it wouldnt look good on web mode

Comment: Changing position in mobile does not affect how it will look in web mode :)

Comment: Yes if i will do it , it will be look ugly in web. then what is your suggest ?

Comment: Reposition image in mobile. No change for web.

Comment: I think facebook dont allowed to use different cover image for different device mode. is it?